# Adding Fragment to TabHost within another Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to add a fragment as one of the tabs in my tabhost on android. I think I need to load the fragment using fragment manager, but I am unsure about how to approach this. Here is my code for setting up the tabHost:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FilesFragment.class);
tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Page 1").setContent(intent).setIndicator("How to Print");
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Page 2").setContent(homePageTab2.getId()).setIndicator("Files");
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Page 3").setContent(homePageTab3.getId()).setIndicator("Drives");
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

This is the run time error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
            at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:747)
            at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
            at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
            at io.uprint.uprint.Home.onCreateView(Home.java:86)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in the logcat...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
```

From the docs for `TabHost`...

> public void setup (LocalActivityManager activityGroup)
>
> If you are using setContent(android.content.Intent), this must be called since the activityGroup is needed to launch the local activity. This is done for you if you extend TabActivity.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *activityGroup*   Used to launch activities for tab content.